# Are the "distended" numbers precisely the numbers for which no two subsets of their divisors have the same sum?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, oeis

The OEIS sequence [A051772](https://oeis.org/A051772) defines the "distended" numbers as those positive integers $n$ for which each divisor of $n$ is greater than the sum of all smaller divisors.

Now, here's a question about such numbers:

> **Question**: Are the "distended" numbers precisely the positive integers $n$ for which the "sum" function from subsets of the divisors of $n$ to the nonnegative integers is injective?

It is easy to show that any "distended" number $n$ satisfies the injectivity condition. Indeed, just write the divisors of $n$ in order from greatest to least as columns and below those columns, write all the binary numbers whose number of digits is at most the number of divisors of $n$, with leading zeros for binary numbers with fewer digits. Then, write a "sum" column that lists the sum of the divisors corresponding to the positions of the digit $1$ for each binary number. Finally, observe that each sum is less than the one below it because $n$ is a "distended" number. In particular, the "sum" column cannot contain any duplicates, so injectivity is satisfied.

What I could not prove is the converse. Perhaps, there might be a deficient counterexample for the converse. Also, any abundant counterexample for the converse would have to be a [weird number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weird_number), for injectivity would imply that the number could not be pseudoperfect. Of course, no abundant number could be a "distended" number.

Comment: Is this true?  How far have you checked?  Semiprimes are all distended, (well other than $6$ I suppose), so a counterexample needs at least $3$ prime factors, possibly not distinct.  Can't have both $2$ and $3$...what about an example like $5\times 11\times 13$?   that's not distended.  I didn't search carefully...am I missing two matching sums?

Comment: @lulu For example, $1 + 65 = 11 + 55$.

Comment: But $175$ seems to be a counterexample.

Comment: Another is $442$.

Comment: @RobertIsrael  Yes, thanks.  Hazards of hastily written code.

Comment: I have just contributed [sequence A332047](https://oeis.org/A332047) to the OEIS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are lots of counterexamples.

Let $p$ be a prime.
Then each prime $q$ between $p^2 - p-1$ and $p^2$, with at most $2016$ exceptions, produces
a counterexample $n = p^2 q$.

Proof:

The divisors of $n = p^2 q$ are $1, p, q, p^2, pq, p^2 q$, in that order if $q$ is in the given interval.  Since $p^2 < 1 + p + q$, $n$ is not distended.

Now there are $64 \cdot 63/2 = 2016$ unordered pairs of distinct sets of divisors.  The sum of the first set minus the sum of the second corresponds to a polynomial of degree $\le 1$ in $q$, which must be $0$ if these two sets have the same sum.  The polynomial 
is never identically $0$, so there is at most one $q$ value where the two sets have the same sum.  Thus, for each $p$, there are at most $2016$ exceptional $q$.

Hmm, too bad this didn't come up $4$ years ago.

Comment: So $575=5^2 \cdot 23$ is a counterexample to the conjectured equivalence, for example. Thanks for creating sequence [A332047](https://oeis.org/A332047) in the OEIS! It remains to ask whether A332047 contains any abundant numbers, which would then necessarily be weird numbers.

Comment: None of the numbers in the b-file for A006037, i.e. the weird numbers up to 6527570, are in the sequence.